# How can I edit my WooCommerce mini cart price and link text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change my WooCommerce mini cart. I've searched a lot but can't find the right filter for this.

This is my current situation:

[image]

Now I want to change the price to get this:

[image]

So I need filter which can change the price there. I need to check if the product is on sale and if this is true I want to add the old price in front of the new price.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `woocommerce_cart_item_price` hook to get the `get_price_html` instead of the price but this hook will modify the price in the mini cart and in the cart page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_item_price', 10, 3 );
function change_item_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price_html();

    return $price;
}
```

if you want to change the price only in the mini cart you can add condition as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_item_price', 10, 3 );
function change_item_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) {
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price_html();
    }

    return $price;
}
```